# Split Excel Cell that has a Formula in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there are way to split an Excel cell that has a formula in it?

For example, the cell has this:

```
=100+200
```

(so when viewing it, it says 300)

And I would like to insert two cells to the right, one with 100 and the other with 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `FILTERXML()`

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=","<t><s>"),"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

If your version of excel do not support dynamic array then try-

```
=FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=","<t><s>"),"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]")
```

and for 2nd value-

```
=FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=","<t><s>"),"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[2]")
```

[image]

Comment: The first TRANSPOSE version didn't work for me, but the second version did. Thank you

Comment: @RodneyEllis First version will work on `Microsoft-365`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this (broken out) but someone may have a better answer ...

**A1** = `=100+200`

**B1** = `=MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,100)`

**C1** = `=LEFT(B1,FIND("+",B1) - 1)`

**D1** = `=MID(B1,FIND("+",B1) + 1, 1000)`

Throw data in a spreadsheet in those cells and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **text to columns** in the Data menu on Excel 365 to specify the delimiter as + that gives you 2 columns with 100 and 200 as text to columns seems to work on the cell formula not the cell value. The solution provided by @Harun24hr is probably better for more complex formula